# Exporting R lists value

Tags: r, excel, list, export

I extracted data from a pdf file, and now i need to export (excel, txt, anything). The data it's in a list format.

I tried

```
capture.output(summary(text_lists), file = "My New File.txt")
```

but the result was

```
>Length Class  Mode     
> [1,] 60     -none- character

> [2,] 62     -none- character

> [3,] 60     -none- character

> [4,] 60     -none- character
```

Then i tried

```
>lapply(text_lists, function(x) write.table( data.frame(x), 'test.csv'  , >append= T))

>[[1]]
>NULL

>[[2]]
>NULL

>[[3]]
>NULL
```

How can i extract the value of the list to be able to export?

Comment: lapply(text_lists, function(x) write.table( data.frame(x), 'test.csv'  , append= T)) worked created a csv file, the list of NULLs returned by the write.table function is expected

Answer (score 0):

the following converts text_lists into a data frame with one column for each list, then outputs a .csv file, each list will be in its own column. Hope this helps to get you toward your goal.

```
maxlen <- max(sapply(text_lists, length))

res <- tibble::as_tibble(do.call(cbind,lapply(text_lists, `length<-`, maxlen)), .name_repair = "universal");

write.csv(res,"test.csv")
```